# If $f:R\to S$ is a homomorphism of commutative rings and $Q$ a primary ideal of $S$, then $Q^{c}=f^{-1}(Q)$ is a primary ideal of $R$

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $f:R\to S$ be a homomorphism of commutative rings, and let $Q$ be a primary ideal of $S$.Then $Q^{c}=f^{-1}(Q)$ is a primary ideal of $R$.

I wonder if $f(R)=Q$ then what happens? I suppose that $f^{-1}(Q)$ is proper ideal of $R$ then I proved it already but how about my case? I can not see the contraction. Can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

You can't have $f(R)=Q$ because commutative ring (with $1$) homomorphisms usually require that $f(1)=1$ but $1\notin Q$ because primary ideals are proper

Comment: I see. OMG, big mistake:) Thank you so much